# Carriage Return Print to Text VB.net

Tags: vb.net, carriage-return

I am trying to print to a text file but I am trying to have my two if statement outputs print on the same line. At the moment each one prints on its own line and i am wondering how I can have them remain on the same one. I tried to do the Replace(vbCrLf, "") but it did not work or perhaps I did not put it in the right place.

```
If (atr.Value = "Cat") Then
    file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} ", attribute.Value, atrue.Value))
End If
If (atr.Value = "Money") Then
    file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} ", attribute.Value, atrue.Value))
End If
```

Output:

```
Cat - 19
Money - H2E
```

Desired output:

```
Cat - 19 Money - H2E
```

Comment: Change `file.WriteLine` to `file.Write`. `WriteLine` means **write a line**, which means it ends with a CR/LF.

Comment: Also, you should use `ElseIf` here to avoid redundant checks: `If atr.Value = "Cat" Then ... ElseIf atr.Value = "Money" Then ... End If`. Or if you have more than two values to check for, you may use a [`Select Case` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) instead.

Comment: Actually, you probably should just use `If atr.Value = "Cat" OrElse atr.Value = "Money" Then ...` since you're executing the same code in both of your current `If` statements.

Comment: Only one of your If statements will execute because atr.Value can't possibly be "Cat" and "Money" at the same time. Your output is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Things are a bit confused here

```
If (atr.Value = "Cat") Then
    file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} ", attribute.Value, atrue.Value))
End If
If (atr.Value = "Money") Then
    file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} ", attribute.Value, atrue.Value))
End If
```

You have 3 variables:

- `atr`
- `atrue`
- `attribute`

I expect one of them is redundant/repeated or a typo.

I also guess that this is being run in a loop where the variable values change on each loop, and that you only want to switch to the next line after you've written "Money"

```
(Some loop)

    'always write the value
    file.Write($"{attribute.Value} - {atrue.Value} "))

    If (atr.Value = "Money") Then file.WriteLine() 'only write a newline if we wrote Money
```

Comment: Yes, i just added a portion of my code so I can just find out how to stop the carriage return between two if statement, no need to focus on variables!

Comment: Perhaps then the answer you seek is as simple as using `Write` Instead of `WriteLine` then